# Restrict a program to use only a specific network adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm using Windows 7, and have various network adapters. Is it possible to restrict a program to only use a specific adapter?

To clear it up a bit more. I'm using VirtualBox, and it creates a host-only network adapter during setup. By that, it's OK all the time. Until I've recently installed WoW, and found out that Battle.net (agent, launcher, etc.) always queries the host-only adapter. Which for sure, doesn't work all the time. Currently, I have to disable the adapter whenever I run the WoW program. So, I've tried to find out if I can block it from using that. I've looked at Windows Firewall and user permission management. But neither gives me a mean to restrict Battle.net from using the adapter.

Any light?

P.S. This question is not specific to Battle.net. It's just happen to be my case. For a long time, I've been always wondering if VB's host-only network adapter would conflict with something. and I've just met the case, at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, turns out a routing table issue. The culprit should be the second entry below:

> 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
>
> 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    276
>
> 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.103    276

My box seems to work fine after I've deleted the entry. And I think it should be fine, unless I use broadcast inside VB.

Comment: What did removing the second entry do for you? .56 is your machine that played Wow?